# Correct way to write copy constructor and assignment operator

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I have a data structure, where I have function Ins(key, value) that insert them into the data structure. I am trying to write copy constructor and assignment operator. I don't know if only this part of code will be enough I can also add the rest. Somehow there is a mistake in this code.

The problem is with Ins(temp -> m_Key, temp -> m_Val); both times.

```
CHash(const CHash & src)
{
  m_Table = new TItem * [src.m_Size];
  TItem * temp = src.m_FirstOrder;
  while (temp != NULL)
  {
    Ins(temp -> m_Key, temp -> m_Val);
    temp = temp -> m_NextOrder;
  }
}

CHash & operator = (const CHash & src)
{
  TItem * temp = m_FirstOrder;
  while (temp != NULL)
  {
    TItem * tmp = temp;
    temp = temp -> m_NextOrder;
    delete tmp;
  }
  delete [] m_Table;

  m_Table = new TItem * [src.m_Size];
  TItem * tmp1 = src.m_FirstOrder;
  while (tmp1 != NULL)
  {
    Ins(tmp1 -> m_Key, tmp1 -> m_Val);
    tmp1 = tmp1 -> m_NextOrder;
  }
}
```

I try this in main and get segfault.

```
CHash hashtable(100);
CHash hash2(50);
hash2 = hashtable;
hashtable.printAll();
hash2.printAll();
CHash b(hash2);
b.printAll();
```

This is the complete code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct TItem {
    TItem(string key, string val, TItem* nextHash,TItem* nextOrd, TItem * prevOrd)
    :m_Key(key),m_Val(val),m_NextHash(nextHash),m_NextOrder(nextOrd),m_PrevOrder(prevOrd){}

    string m_Key,m_Val;
    TItem * m_NextHash, * m_NextOrder, * m_PrevOrder;
};

class CHash{
public:
    CHash (int m) : m_Table(NULL),m_Size(m),m_FirstOrder(NULL),m_LastOrder(NULL)
    {
      m_Table = new TItem * [m];
      for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        m_Table[i] = NULL;
    }

    ~CHash()
    {
      TItem * temp = m_FirstOrder;
      while (temp != NULL)
      {
        TItem * tmp = temp;
        temp = temp -> m_NextOrder;
        delete tmp;
      }
      delete [] m_Table;
    }

    bool IsSet(string key)
    {
      TItem * temp = m_Table[hashFn(key)];
      if (temp == NULL)
      {
        return false;
      }
      while (temp != NULL)
      {
        if (temp -> m_Key == key)
        {
          return true;
        }
        temp = temp -> m_NextHash;
      }
      return false;
    }

    CHash(const CHash & src)
    {
      m_Size = src.m_Size;
      m_Table = new TItem * [src.m_Size];
      for (int i = 0; i < src.m_Size; i++)
        m_Table[i] = NULL;
      TItem * temp = src.m_FirstOrder;
      while (temp != NULL)
      {
        Ins(temp -> m_Key, temp -> m_Val);
        temp = temp -> m_NextOrder;
      }
    }

    CHash & operator = (const CHash & src)
    {
      m_Size = src.m_Size;
      TItem * temp = m_FirstOrder;
      while (temp != NULL)
      {
        TItem * tmp = temp;
        temp = temp -> m_NextOrder;
        delete tmp;
      }
      delete [] m_Table;

      m_Table = new TItem * [src.m_Size];
      for (int i = 0; i < src.m_Size; i++)
        m_Table[i] = NULL;
      TItem * tmp1 = src.m_FirstOrder;
      while (tmp1 != NULL)
      {
        Ins(tmp1 -> m_Key, tmp1 -> m_Val);
        tmp1 = tmp1 -> m_NextOrder;
      }
    }

    bool Ins(const string & key, const string & val)
    {
      string help = key;
      if (IsSet(help))
        return false;
      //first element added ever
      if (m_FirstOrder == NULL)
      {
        TItem * tmp01 = new TItem(key, val, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        m_Table[hashFn(help)] = tmp01;
        m_FirstOrder = m_LastOrder = tmp01;
      }
      else
      {
        TItem * temp = m_Table[hashFn(help)];
        //first added to that hash
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
          TItem * tmp02 = new TItem(key, val, NULL, NULL, m_LastOrder);
          m_Table[hashFn(help)] = tmp02;
          m_LastOrder -> m_NextOrder = tmp02;
          m_LastOrder = tmp02;
        }
        else
        {
          while (temp -> m_NextHash != NULL)
          {
            temp = temp -> m_NextHash;
          }
          TItem * tmp03 = new TItem(key, val, NULL, NULL, m_LastOrder);
          temp -> m_NextHash = tmp03;
          m_LastOrder -> m_NextOrder = tmp03;
          m_LastOrder = tmp03;
        }
      }
      return true;
    }

    bool Del (const string & key)
    {
      string help = key;
      if (!IsSet(help))
        return false;

      TItem * temp = m_Table[hashFn(help)];

      if (temp == NULL)
        return false;


      while (temp != NULL)
      {
        if (temp -> m_Key == key)
          break;
        temp = temp -> m_NextHash;
      }

      if (temp == NULL)
        return false;

      if (m_FirstOrder == temp)
        m_FirstOrder = m_FirstOrder -> m_NextOrder;
      else
        temp -> m_PrevOrder -> m_NextOrder = temp -> m_NextOrder;
      if (m_LastOrder == temp)
        m_LastOrder = m_LastOrder -> m_PrevOrder;

      m_Table[hashFn(help)] = temp -> m_NextHash;
      delete temp;
      return true;
    }

    template <typename func>
    void ForEach(func f)
    {

    }
    void printAll()
    {
      cout << "PRINTING" << endl;
      TItem * temp = m_FirstOrder;
      while (temp != NULL)
      {
        cout << "  :  " << temp -> m_Val << " : ";
        temp = temp -> m_NextOrder;
      }
      cout << endl;
    }

private:
    TItem **        m_Table;
    unsigned int    m_Size;
    TItem *         m_FirstOrder, * m_LastOrder;
    unsigned int hashFn(string & str){
        std::hash<std::string> hash_fn;
        return hash_fn(str)%m_Size;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    CHash hashtable(100);
    CHash hash2(50);
    hashtable.Ins("h1","car");
    assert ( !hashtable.Ins("h1","phone"));
    hashtable.Ins("h2","field");
    hashtable.Ins("h3","house");
    hashtable.Ins("h4","tree");
    hashtable.printAll();
    assert ( hashtable.Del("h3") );
    assert ( !hashtable.Ins("h4","tree") );
    assert(!hashtable.Del("h4d"));
    assert(hashtable.Del("h1"));
    assert(!hashtable.Del("h3"));
    assert(!hashtable.Del("h1"));
    hash2 = hashtable;
    hashtable.printAll();
    hash2.printAll();
    CHash b(hash2);
    b.printAll();


    hashtable.ForEach([](TItem * it ){
        cout<<it->m_Key<<" - "<<it->m_Val<<endl;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

I run it like this:  g++ -std=c++11 -g filename.cpp

Comment: First of all you should run your code in the debugger, and step through line by line to identify where it actually happened from the call stack. Then set breakpoints the way down there and check if all the variables are in expected state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several problems in your code.

1. The assignment operator doesn't return `*this`.
2. The copy constructor doesn't initialize `m_FirstOrder` and `m_LastOrder`.
3. Lots of copypaste making the code hard to read and error-prone.

If we fix the problems we get:

```
class CHash{
public:
    CHash (int m)
    {
      initialize(m);
    }

    ~CHash()
    {
      finalize();
    }

    CHash(const CHash & src)
    {
      initialize(src.m_Size);
      copy(src.m_FirstOrder);
    }

    CHash & operator = (const CHash & src)
    {
      if (&src == this)
        return;
      finalize();
      initialize(src.m_Size);
      copy(src.m_FirstOrder);
      return *this;
    }

    ...

private:
    ...

    void initialize(int m)
    {
      m_Size = m;
      m_Table = new TItem * [m];
      for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        m_Table[i] = NULL;
      m_FirstOrder = NULL;
      m_LastOrder  = NULL;
    }

    void finalize()
    {
      TItem * temp = m_FirstOrder;
      while (temp != NULL)
      {
        TItem * tmp = temp;
        temp = temp -> m_NextOrder;
        delete tmp;
      }
      delete [] m_Table;
    }

    void copy(TItem *src)
    {
      while (src != NULL)
      {
        Ins(src -> m_Key, src -> m_Val);
        src = src -> m_NextOrder;
      }
    }
};
```

I wonder though, why you don't use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` and `std::vector<TItem*>` instead of `TItem**`...

Comment: Thank you so much. As for nullptr, didn't know the difference until now and STL is forbidden in this task.

Comment: The copy assignment operator is not protecting from self-assignment. And in general, a copy assignment operator can be implemented using the copy constructor to ensure exception safety and avoid code repetition, eg: `CHash & operator = (const CHash & src) { if (&src != this) { CHash(src).swap(*this); } return *this; }` You would just need to add a  `swap()` method to swap data members between 2 `CHash` objects since STL (`std::swap()`) can't be used.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, good point. One of many more improvements one can make in this code.